# find the doc string for builtins such as the "print" function

Tags: python, built-in, docstring

usually when i create a function in python, the doc string is written like this:

```py
def some_function(n):
    """ the docstring describing the function
    
    inputs:
        n (str): name of the person

    return:
        returns hello and the name    
    """
    a = 'hello '
    return a + n
```

So when i hover over the function in an editor (like `vscode`), the doc string pops up describing the inputs for the user to conveniently read.

The user can then `go to definition` to see the original function. They would see the function with it's doc string.

However, when i try to `go to definition` for the built-in `print` function, i cannot find the doc string (even though i can see that it exists).

The definition takes me to `builtins.pyi` and there i can see the function which looks like this:

```py
@overload
def print(
    *values: object,
    sep: str | None = ...,
    end: str | None = ...,
    file: SupportsWrite[str] | None = ...,
    flush: Literal[False] = ...,
) -> None: ...
@overload
def print(
    *values: object, sep: str | None = ..., end: str | None = ..., file: _SupportsWriteAndFlush[str] | None = ..., flush: bool
) -> None: ...
```

In fact i can see two `print` functions defined in this module.

However, i cannot the the docstring anywhere, so where is it created or where does it exist?

Comment: because `print` is implemented in C, your IDE is going to the typing stub, not the actual source code of the `print` function

Comment: The doc strings of built-in objects in pythons is a feature of VsCode.

Comment: you could use the `help` function to see the docstring of any function, if available. e.g `help(print)`

Comment: @heretolearn which I believe just prints the `__doc__` attribute.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga.  I was unaware of what you refer to as the `stub file` but have now looked up what this means. So is one able to navigate to or view the C file where the function was originally implemented in that respect ?

Comment: @D.L not from the IDE. But CPython is open-source and the code is hosted on github